# Show that Sufficient statistic is complete

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, complete-statistics

I have the following  Gamma$(2,\theta)$ distribution:

$$f_\theta(x) = \theta^2x e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{1}_{[0,+\infty[}(x) $$

I am asked the two following questions:

```
Show that the model belongs to the exponential family and exhibits a sufficient statistic S

Prove that S is complete.
```

I think that the model belongs to an exponential family with  $h(x) = \theta^{2}x\mathbb{1}_{[0,+\infty[}(x)$

and that the sufficient statistic is -x.

I am not sure though to show how S Is complete, do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: please add `self-study` tag and add precisions about applying the definitions.

Comment: Conventional terminology: a distribution with density $\theta^2x e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{1}_{[0,+\infty[}(x)$ is not an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). It's a special case of the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).